# What contributes to success and survival when exploring wasteland?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, what are the factors that contribute to dweller exploring the wasteland will...

- survive
- find something valuable

and how significant is the contribution of each factor?

Comment: @user1337 thanks, my question is a bit different but really close. I think it may be closed.